# How to represent parent-child relationship between two records/maps?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I am trying to represent gui elements in Clojure/Script. The problem is that the elements are nested and need to communicate with each other. I thought to pass references to each other, but it seems I can't just pass mutual references to each other, as I naively thought.

Code I tried

```
(defrecord Element [position size parent children state type value])
(def parent (atom (Element. ...)))
(def child  (atom (Element. ...)))
(assoc @parent :child child)
(assoc @child :parent parent)
```

this doesn't work.

What is the idiomatic solution in Clojure for this kind of problem?

---

Update: mutual referencing doesn't seem to work:

```
(defrecord Element [position size parent children state type value])

(def parent (atom (Element. {:x 0 :y 0} {:width 1600 :height 900} nil nil :collapsed :container nil)))

(def child (atom (Element. {:x 5 :y 5} {:width 100 :height 100} nil nil :collapsed :container nil)))

(swap! parent assoc :child child)
(swap! child assoc :parent parent)

#object[InternalError InternalError: too much recursion]
   cljs.core.PersistentArrayMap.prototype.cljs$core$ILookup$_lookup$arity$2 (jar
:file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojurescript/1.10.520/clojuresc
ript-1.10.520.jar!/cljs/core.cljs:6811:10)
```

Maybe in Clojure you don't do mutual references?

Comment: Have you had a look at reagent and/or rum? I think most ClojureScript gui apps are built using re-frame (for reagent) or citrus (for rum) to take care of the need for component to communicate with each other.

Comment: @PEZ For my purposes, I need to build a custom gui, its for internal tooling for a lite game engine.

Comment: Cool. I still can recommend using `citrus`, it is actually not dependent on `rum` at all.

Comment: @PEZ, I didn't realise libraries like these existed, I can have citrus deal with state, while the drawing is done by custom code. I am going to use this in the next version. Thanks

Comment: You will not regret it. I can recommend the README of re-frame to get acquainted with the philosophy behind these libraries: https://github.com/Day8/re-frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're `assoc`iating the parent to the child, but then throwing away the new `Element`. You need to set the value in the atom using `reset!` or `swap!`:

```
(swap! parent assoc :child child)  ; Equivalent to (swap! parent #(assoc % :child child))
(swap! child assoc :parent parent)
```

[`swap!`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/swap!) is similar to [`update`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/update), but it replaces the value held within an `atom`.

---

Also note, you gave a field the name `children`, but in your example, you're referring to it using `:child`. `children` suggests multiple children though, so I'd change it to start as a vector instead of `nil`, then `conj` to it. I'd also create a `new-element` helper:

```
(defrecord Element [position size parent children state type value])

(defn new-element [position size]
  (->Element position size nil [] :collapsed :container nil))

(def parent (atom (new-element {:x 0 :y 0} {:width 1600 :height 900})))
(def child (atom (new-element {:x 5 :y 5} {:width 100 :height 100})))

(swap! parent update :children conj child)
(swap! child assoc :parent parent)
```

---

To address the error that you're getting, it runs fine for me in *Clojure*.

If I print `parent` and `child` after the above code runs, I get an infinite output because to print the parent you need to print the child, and to print the child you need to print the parent... It still works for me though.

Make sure that error isn't coming about because you're trying to print the structure out in a REPL.

This could also be a limitation of Clojurescript. I can't answer for that unfortunately since I'm not familiar with Cljs.

I'll delete my answer if this ends up not being helpful.

---

I'll also note that nesting atoms isn't a great idea. `atom`s are really mutable containers to hold immutable objects. It may be cleaner to have an ID system, and have each parent/child hold a numeric ID to it's child/parent. Then you have one single atom for your whole program. The atoms can hold a map of ID->element for easy lookups.

Comment: I tried it, but it created problems, I can't include the code in comments, please see my answer for updates.

Comment: @maou And also see my edit at the very bottom. There's likely better ways than nesting atoms. I don't think I've ever had the need to hold one atom inside of another.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am going to look into mapping elements with IDs.